Django (rest framework) performance of queryset union versus Q versus other ideas
I am creating a search functionality that searches through multiple models that have relations to my main model. Using Django rest framework I then return a paginated result back on every object of my main model that is related to the search query. As the searches are quite "wildcard" like and search in text fields I want to make this as performant (good performance?) as possible.
Currently I have implemented it using queryset unions, thinking at least the querysets are lazy loading. When trying to implement it using Q() I had to go through getting the actual foreign key constraints IDs as value_lists and I think that makes for more computation needed? But I don't have a good sense on what is what in terms of performance.
To clarify performance: I want low CPU and memory usage on the host itself (these are EC2 instances in AWS) and am slightly less concerned about DB performance (RDS instance in AWS) but it is of course still important.
So the question is: How do I make this performing best?
The models all have the modelMain as a normal foreingkeyconstraint except modelB that is a many-to-many relationship.
Current code:
    def get_queryset(self):
        search_query = self.request.query_params.get('search_query', None)
        modelA_used = self.request.query_params.get('modelA', 'not_used')
        modelB_used = self.request.query_params.get('modelB', 'not_used')
        modelMain_description = self.request.query_params.get('description', 'not_used')
        modelMain_subject = self.request.query_params.get('modelMain_subject', 'not_used')
        modelC_used = self.request.query_params.get('modelC', 'not_used')

        if search_query:
            queryset = modelMain.objects.none()
            if modelMain_description == 'used':
                queryset = queryset.union(modelMain.objects.filter(description__icontains=search_query))
            if modelMain_subject == 'used':
                queryset = queryset.union(modelMain.objects.filter(subject__icontains=search_query))
            if modelA_used == 'used':
                modelA_results = modelA.objects.filter(raw_data__icontains=search_query).only('modelMain')
                queryset = queryset.union(modelMain.objects.filter(modelA__in=modelA_results))
            if modelB_used == 'used':
                modelB_results = modelB.objects.filter(modelB__icontains=search_query).only('modelMain')
                queryset = queryset.union(modelMain.objects.filter(modelB__in=modelB_results))
            if modelC_used == 'used':
                modelC_results = modelC.objects.filter(value__icontains=search_query)
                queryset = queryset.union(modelMain.objects.filter(modelC__in=modelC).distinct())
        return queryset

EDIT: I actually ended up deploying it using Q() so that I could still use django filters for more filtering (otherwise we have issues with Union). Q() does have the same idea as separate filters in unions, so no addition to the code was needed except for rewriting the union to ||Q(). But am still curious about the performance question, which is better?
